# Generating Files from Web SRC URLs

Tags: java, intellij-idea, web-scraping, jsoup

I have this odd issue on my program that I can't seem to figure out. It works fine on Mac, but on Windows, it does not. The program purpose is to scrape a URL for all the pictures on the page, then save it to a file. I believe the main issue is that Windows is trying to look for the file equal to the name of the SRC URL the picture is hosted on, instead of generating the picture file from that name.

**Error I'm Getting:**

```
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Downloads\rUqSTMN09zEXEdpicCS4lnNynf-NXrTxm88.png (The system cannot find the path specified)`
```

**Edit- changed error**

I need a way to either make a blank file with the name of the SRC and overwrite it, or create a file with the name of the SRC. Any ideas?

```
    int indexName = src.lastIndexOf("/");
    if (indexName == src.length()){
        src = src.substring(1,indexName);
    }

    indexName = src.lastIndexOf("/");
    String name = src;
```

Then I use OutputStream to try and create the file. Using FileOutputStream throws the same error.

`OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(folderPath + name));`

**Edit - Extra Code**

```
    int indexName = src.lastIndexOf("/");

    if (indexName == src.length()){
        src = src.substring(1,indexName);
    }
    indexName = src.lastIndexOf("/");

    String name = src;
    name = name.replace(":",""); // replace all ":" with ""
    name = name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9-.]", "");
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length() - 3; i++){ //replaces all but the last "." for the file extention
        name = name.replaceFirst(".","");
    }
```

**Attempted Fixes**

- URLname.replace(":", "");

Comment: Well yes, you can't name a folder `https:` with a colon in windows.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Ah! thank you! What would be the best way to take out this colon?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas EDIT: I tried removing ":" using replace(), no luck.

Comment: You need to post your entire code where you come up with the file name.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Posted. Check the error as well, it is different. If you need anything else please let me know.

Comment: Your new error just means that there is no file with that name at that location. Did you make sure `C:\Downloads` exists? (That's not going to be your windows downloads folder, which is down in C:\Users\<username>\Downloads)

Comment: @roddyofthefrozenpeas yes it exists

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas fixing tag